# Parse large strings to invoke JS functions in Node

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, parsing, indexof

This is my first attempt at building a Node module; the purpose is to parse a file (typically an HTML file), look for specific matches, and do something with those matches.

I'm using the `fs` module to `readdir`, find each file in that directory, and then pass off each file to `readFile`, which returns the contents of the file as a string.

What I'm looking to achieve is to search the contents of the file (or the long string) for specific matches, get any related parameters, and then pass the file and its parameters off to a function which will do other manipulation. In my mind it would be make sense to just look for data attributes in the HTML. For example, if I were to search this string:

```
<a href="/">
    <img class="site-logo" src="..." data-option="site-logo true" />
</a>
```

I'd want to find `data-option` and pass it, along with `site-logo true` and the file name to a function as parameters.

In my searching I've come across using things like `indexOf()` or the `search()` method and pass an array of strings to match against, but I'm concerned that for larger files this would become extremely blocking (eventually I'll learn to use the `async` module...), so I'm wondering if the SO community had any clever suggestions for doing this.

Should I be using something like [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)? If so, how would I use it for other file types (non-HTML)? Maybe a Regex?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use something like [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) for HTML content. For non-HTML resources, it depends on the format, there may be modules on npm to deal with those other formats. If not, regex is probably your next best bet.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go and see where I get :)